# Atualizar uma variável PHP dentro do JavaScript num intervalo de tempo

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Temos uma consulta postgresql dentro de uma função javascript que é a seguinte:

```
function  valor(){  
    <?php 
        $con_string = "host='ip' port=numero dbname='banco' user='usuario' password='***'";
        $conn = pg_connect($con_string);
        $query="SELECT tubeteira from velocidadereal";
        $output=pg_query($conn,$query);
        $retorna =  pg_fetch_array($output);
        $valor = $retorna["tubeteira"];
    ?>

    return <?php echo $valor ?>;
} 

setInterval(valor,1000);
```

Porém embora ele atualize de 1 em um segundo a variável php não está atualizando na função, então ao alterar o valor no banco de dados da coluna onde estamos realizando o select ele não retorna o novo valor a não ser que demos refresh na página.

Como posso fazer com que atualize automaticamente?

Importante ressaltar que a consulta está alimentando um gráfico.

Comment: Essa consulta do PHP é executada uma única vez, pelo servidor, apenas no carregamento da página, independentemente de você chamar a função valor() várias vezes, pois ela está no lado do cliente. Para que a variável atualize você precisará fazer a consulta no PHP via ajax. Acredito que alguém lhe dará uma resposta com um exemplo. Fiz o comentário apenas para um entendimento inicial.

Comment: Obrigada pelo comentário. Fico no aguardo de um exemplo.

Comment: Renata, você colocou "Temos uma consulta postgresql dentro de uma função AJAX que é a seguinte:" Mas não tem nenhum função AJAX aí.
Recomendo esse artigo para você: https://www.devmedia.com.br/executando-consultas-ao-mysql-com-php-e-ajax/26008

Answer (score 4):

PHP é uma linguagem `server-side` (que funciona ao lado do servidor). Javascript é uma linguagem `client-side` (que funciona do lado do cliente [leia-se "navegador"]).

Você não pode executar uma função Javascript esperando que e isso afete o comportamento de uma variável PHP. Isso é o como esperar que uma "mágica aconteça".

A solução que você pode aplicar em tais casos são inúmeras, mas aqui vou citar uma delas:

- Fazer requisição AJAX de X em X períodos.
- Usar um Websocket

Um exemplo de como fazer com o AJAX:

1. Crie um script PHP para retornar os dados em JSON.

Código:

```
$con_string = "host='ip' port=numero dbname='banco' user='usuario' 
password='***'";
$conn = pg_connect($con_string);
$query="SELECT tubeteira from velocidadereal";
$output=pg_query($conn,$query);
$retorna =  pg_fetch_array($output);
$valor = $retorna["tubeteira"];


header('Content-Type: application/json');

exit(json_encode(['valor' => $valor]));
```

Crie uma função no Javascript que faça a requisição através de AJAX:

```
 function valor(valor) {
     // faça alguma coisa como  valor obtido de 1 em 1 segundo
 }

setInterval(function atualizarValor() {

    if (atualizarValor.executando) return;

    atualizarValor.executando = true;

     $.ajax({
         url: '/script_json.php',
         success: function (response) {

            valor(response.valor);

            atualizarValor.executando = false;
         }
     }) 
}, 1000);
```

**Observação**: Cuidado com a quantidade de requisições feitas no seu servidor, pois isso pode prejudicar a performance dele, dependendo do número de usuários X requisições simultâneos.