# Rota com variavel

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Gostaria de saber no Laravel, ao dizer o nome da rota, ele aceita a variável, ao invés do próprio nome, como por exemplo:

Exemplo: Ao invés de ser assim:

```
{{ route('minhaRota') }}
```

Ser assim:

```
   var minhaRota = 'minhaRota'  
   {{ route( minhaRota ) }}
```

Só que assim ele me dá um aviso de Constante não definida

Estou tentando fazer isso com javascript

Como quero fazer reaproveitamento de código, e vou usar a mesma página para outros tipos de operações, não gostaria de ficar copiando codigo para outro arquivo, gostaria apenas de enviar uma variável com a rota atual para ao finalizar determinada operação voltar para onde estava.

Para obter a rota atual estou usando assim:

```
let currentUrl = '{{ Route::getCurrentRoute()->action['as'] }}'
```

Então envio essa url atual para um formulário para que quando terminar a operação (salvar, editar) ele volte para onde ele estava antes a `currentUrl`

Comment: Do jeito que vocês fez é como se houvesse uma constante no PHP.  JavaScript e PHP não compartilham da mesma variável, são coisas diferentes. Conte o que deseja fazer!

Comment: Opa, boa tarde a melhor maneira de você fazer isso é usar uma lib que já existe, o nome é laroute, dá uma pesquisada, vale a pena.

https://github.com/aaronlord/laroute

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Igualar variável php a uma variável javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25136/igualar-vari%c3%a1vel-php-a-uma-vari%c3%a1vel-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você parece estar querendo fazer algo impossível: Chamar uma função do PHP passando uma variável do Javascript como parâmetro.

Mas uma vez falando: [PHP é Server-Side, Javascript é Client-Side](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/312539/4995).

```
var minhaRota = 'minhaRota'; // Essa variável é do Javascript
{{ route( minhaRota ) }} // Essa chamada ocorre no PHP, não no Javascript
```

Logo é compreensível que o PHP diga que é uma constante indefinida. Aliás, as sintaxes de definição de variáveis do PHP é completamente diferente do Javascript [acho que você deveria ter percebido isso].

Eu não entendi muito bem o que você quer fazer, mas se você quer pegar a rota atual, não é algo muito difícil de se fazer no Laravel.

Eu usaria o atributo `data-` para isso. Assim:

```
<body data-route="{{ request()->route()->action['as'] or false }}"></body>
```

No Javascript, você pode fazer assim:

```
let currentUrl = document.body.dataset.route;
```

**Observação**: É claro, você vai definir isso no seu layout principal (supondo que você tem um, pois se não tiver, a sua ideia de "reutilização de código" já foi pro espaço).

Comment: Então será mais fácil pegar a url atual, porque meu body está em outras telas

Comment: Jovem, mas qual é o problema de estar em outras telas? O que vai interferir no funcionamento de outras páginas?

Comment: Veja que, se não existir o nome da rota, ele simplesmente retornará `false`. Não vai mudar em nada pra você.

Comment: Pra mim retornou `1`

Comment: @adventistaam 1? não sei se houve alguma mudança na versão do laravel, porque o `or` é um atalho para `isset`. tente remover o `or false` e faça o teste.

Comment: Retornou a rota atual.  Como eu faria para usar no meu form action ou não tem como? {{ route( oRetorno ) }}

Comment: @adventistaam você teria que manipular o `form` pelo Javascript, saca? Você poderia fazer um `document.querySelector('#id_do_form').action = currentUrl`

Comment: Ele já reconheceria como rota?

Comment: Ainda não......