# Executar PHP dentro da Função JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, sql

Pessoal tenho a seguinte função sendo chamada por onclick, o problema é que não consigo usar variável JavaScript no php, alguém tem uma ideia de como faço essa função?

function fila(id){

```
var idBanco = id;
console.log(variaveljs);

<?php
    $sql = "UPDATE `tabelaclientespos` SET `empresa` = '2' WHERE       
     `tabelaclientespos`.`Id` = idBanco";
    mysqli_query($conn,$sqlTempo);
?>
```

}

Comment: Outra: [Passar variável php para javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58958/5878)

Comment: [Como passar variáveis entre páginas PHP via JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12241/5878)

Comment: [Atualizar uma variável PHP dentro do JavaScript num intervalo de tempo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/312504/5878)

Comment: Se nenhuma dessas lhe atender, por favor, edite sua pergunta e esclareça melhor o problema.

Answer (score -1):

Não é melhor fazer ao contrário? Coloque a função javascript dentro das tags  e chame-a ou não usando o PHP.

```
<?php
echo "<script>
          var idBanco = id;
          console.log(variaveljs);
          ".funcaophpaqui()."
          var x = ".$varphp."
      </script>";
?>
```